# Is there a way to see the count of Arqade unanswered questions over time?

Tags: support

I was looking at the [Arqade unanswered feed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/unanswered) and noticed that it has a count of the unanswered questions on the site.

[image]

I've been making an effort to reduce the list by upvoting answers as well as answering questions myself. Still, I would like to know if there is a graph that plots the growth of unanswered questions. I want to check if this number is trending upwards or downwards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, through [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/gaming/query/1136552/answered-unanswered-questions-by-month#graph)

[image]

Comment: Perfect. Do you know, by chance, what was the cause of the spikes in 2012 and mid 2016?

Comment: @PausePause i know in 2016 it was because of Pokemon Go coming out, trying to recall what the 2012 spike was for

Comment: @PausePause Given the spike in 2012 looks to be carried over from late 2011, my guess would be Skyrim

Comment: That makes sense. Skyrim wouldn't surprise me. I can envision Minecraft coming into popularity around the same time too.

Comment: Diablo 3 was released in may of 2012 ‍♀️

Comment: And the overall declination of questions asked is due to the increasing popularity of alternative, game-specific platforms, mostly? Does anyone know?

Comment: @Joachim It could be a number of things. Users could be migrating to alternative sites where the rules are not as strict to freely ask whatever kind of question they want. To my knowledge, there hasn't been a game released in a while that was on the scale of games like Skyrim, Pokemon Go, or Minecraft that prompted so many questions. And the scope of any given game is limited - the amount of questions can only go so far until all the answers are found. That's my 2 cents on your question